# Issue with login system in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an issue with my login system and seek for some geek help when using the first made user (admin) the system does what it needs to do. But when I try to login with a different user it won't work. And I get my error `username and password unknown`, when I remove following lines from the code I can login with all other users,

```
   ElseIf (currentUser <> username AndAlso currentPassword <> password) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Username and password unknown", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
Return False
```

Source code,

```
Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
    Dim usersDatasSet As New DataSet()
    usersDataAdapter.FillSchema(usersDatasSet, SchemaType.Source, "Users")
    usersDataAdapter.Fill(usersDatasSet, "Users")
    Dim table As DataTable = usersDatasSet.Tables("Users")

    For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim currentUser As String = table.Rows(i)("Username").ToString().Trim()
        Dim currentPassword As String = table.Rows(i)("Password").ToString().Trim()


        'Check input

        If (currentUser <> username And currentPassword = password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown user", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False

        ElseIf (currentUser = username And currentPassword <> password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False


        ElseIf (currentUser <> username AndAlso currentPassword <> password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and  password unknown", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False

        ElseIf (currentUser = username AndAlso currentPassword = password) Then
            usersDatasSet.Dispose()
            Connection.Close()
            Return True
        End If

    Next
    usersDatasSet.Dispose()
    Connection.Close()
    Return False
End Function
```

Thanks for any help in this issue.

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET provided database or your own database?

Comment: What are you logging *into*?

Comment: Why are you looping through the rows in your users table?  You should be selecting 1 row based on the username, not the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

You're looping through the rows in your table, checking each row's value against the user supplied values of UserName and Password.

Since you're first user is Admin, Admin will always be able to logon.

Any other user will fail, because of your `ElseIf (currentUser <> username AndAlso currentPassword <> password) Then` block (You're trying to log in with John, but you're using Admin's credentials).

When you remove the `ElseIf (currentUser <> username AndAlso currentPassword <> password) Then` any user can log in - because they're actually logging in as Admin.

Try selecting the user from the table and comparing the username and password to the supplied values.

**What You Should Do**

In order to validate that the user can log in, you can do the following (instead of your For loop):

```
Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean

    ' Set a flag for whether or not login was successful
    Dim LoggedIn As Boolean = False
    Dim usersDatasSet As New DataSet()
    usersDataAdapter.FillSchema(usersDatasSet, SchemaType.Source, "Users")
    usersDataAdapter.Fill(usersDatasSet, "Users")
    Dim table As DataTable = usersDatasSet.Tables("Users")

    ' This will return an array of DataRows that have the specified
    ' username in them.
    ' You will need to have unique usernames for this to work
    Dim credentials() As DataRow = table.Select("Username = '" + username + "'")

    If (credentials.Length = 1) Then
        Dim currentUser As String = credentials(0)("Username").ToString()
        Dim currentPassword As String = credentials(0)("Password").ToString()

        If (currentUser <> username And currentPassword = password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown user", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ElseIf (currentUser = username And currentPassword <> password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ElseIf (currentUser <> username AndAlso currentPassword <> password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and  password unknown", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ElseIf (currentUser = username AndAlso currentPassword = password) Then
            LoggedIn = True
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Mulitple users found for " & username, "Error", MessageBox.Buttons.OK, MessageBox.Icon.Error)
    End If

    usersDatasSet.Dispose()
    Connection.Close()

    Return LoggedIn
End Function
```

This will allow you to tell the user if it was the username or password that failed the validation, and handle if you have multiple users with the same username.

**However**

I would discourage you from using a system like that (telling the user which part of the login failed), as it could give hackers information if they are trying a brute force attack.  (Yeah, I know, probably a little overparanoid here).

It would be better to simplify it like this:

```
Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean

    ' Set a flag for whether or not login was successful
    Dim LoggedIn As Boolean = False
    Dim usersDatasSet As New DataSet()
    usersDataAdapter.FillSchema(usersDatasSet, SchemaType.Source, "Users")
    usersDataAdapter.Fill(usersDatasSet, "Users")
    Dim table As DataTable = usersDatasSet.Tables("Users")

    ' This will return an array of DataRows that have the specified
    ' username in them.
    ' You will need to have unique usernames for this to work
    Dim credentials() As DataRow = table.Select("Username = '" + username + "' AND Password = '" + password + "'")

    If (credentials.Length =1 ) Then
        LoggedIn = True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password combination", "Error", MessageButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    usersDatasSet.Dispose()
    Connection.Close()

    Return LoggedIn
End Function
```

Now, a much better approach and even more secure would have the following elements:

1. The password is hashed (with a salt) and stored in your database.
     1a.  You'll have to hash (with the correct salt) the user's plain text password that they enter and compare it with the hash stored in the table for their username for them to successfully log in.
2. Limit the number of tries - if they exceed the number of tries (say 3, for example), the account is locked. This prevents brute force attacks.
3. Use a paramaterized query against the table to prevent SQL Injection Attacks.  I realize this is most likely a WinForms app (based on the calls to MessageBox), but parameterized queries are a good coding practice to get into.